# What's the difference between '=' and '==' in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

Recently I read some codes written by others. And I found a SQL sentence like this `select * from quickdial where deleted== 0;` It's invalid in MySQL, but it runs OK in SQLite3.

However I am always using this form `select * from quickdial where deleted=0;`. I am really curious about it. What's the differences between these two forms? And which one is more efficient? Any reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that both `=` and `==` are the same, which means equals. Though there's no differences between them, it would be better to use `=` instead of `==` because it's SQL standard for equals operator.

Both `!=` and `<>` means not equal. These are also the same.

You can read the document about [operators in sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#binaryops).